# Unable to install rubygems - curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'production.cf.rubygems.org'

Tags: ubuntu, curl, dns, rubygems, rvm

I am unable to install rubygems on ubuntu.

Below is the logs of termial.

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it for your system only.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/stcadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may    take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your connection...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8770k  100 8770k    0     0  96981      0  0:01:32  0:01:32 --:--:--  220k
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p320 to /home/stcadmin/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #configuring..........................................
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #compiling...................................................................
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #installing...
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #making binaries executable.
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #downloading rubygems-2.1.11
Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 3 retries left.
Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 2 retries left.
Warning: Transient problem: timeout Will retry in 2 seconds. 1 retries left.
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'production.cf.rubygems.org'
There was an error(6).
Checking fallback: ftp://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.1.11.tgz
Checking fallback:   http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-2.1.11.tgz
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

There has been an error while trying to fetch rubygems. 
Halting the installation.
```

Comment: `nslookup production.cf.rubygems.org
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
production.cf.rubygems.org canonical name = d2chzxaqi4y7f8.cloudfront.net.
Name: d2chzxaqi4y7f8.cloudfront.net
Address: 54.230.96.223`

Comment: It was a problem with your DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following error message:

> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'production.cf.rubygems.org'
>
> There was an error(6).

the issue may relate to network or DNS resolution. Found what might be a relevant thread here - [resolving host](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141488) relating to a package (not ruby gems). The very last line is:

`sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`

You can check out the `rsolv.conf` by using your `cat` command. The file is used to configure domain name system resolver library. You can read more here in this [wiki article bout resolv.conf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf).